# Cannot connect mysql db via php

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection

My db name is: BNCPRODUCTIONS

And here is how i connect to it:

```
$db = mysql_connect( "localhost", "", "" ) or die( "Cannot make connection" );
mysql_select_db('BNCPRODUCTIONS') or die( "Cannot connect to db" );
```

But for some reason, it does not connect to it, why?

Comment: ya i included no username and password for my database.

Comment: i know its not the connection issue, because i get the second die error "Cannot connect to db".

Comment: username should have something in it.  What is the error message you are getting?  If you using a program like `heidisql` http://www.heidisql.com/ what message do you receive when trying to connect?

Comment: @Dave, does the database actually exist yet?

Comment: have you tried to print out the error instead just killing the script ? die( mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() );

Comment: @Dave, if the database does exist does the user trying to access it have permissions to that particular db?

Comment: yes it does.  I created it in my phpadmin account

Comment: oh shiit ur right, i get access denied.  How do set permission in phpmyadmin?

Comment: just set the password for `root` and use `root` for developing purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time insteand of stackoverflow use

```
 die( mysql_error( $db ));
```

It will tell you much more, and just for convience enable errors

```
  error_reporting( E_ALL );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a username or password set up, don't specify them as an empty string. Just use mysql_connect(dbname).

Comment: that didn't solve the issue.  But i found out what it was, i was getting access denied.